# Can you generate new PayPal IPNs for past (IPN-less) transactions?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

So I'm working with a system that uses the legacy NVP/IPN thing from PayPal. The IPN listener URL wasn't set up properly and so they ran a couple weeks worth of transactions with no IPN data coming back. I've set it up properly now, but I'm wondering if there is a way to regenerate that last couple weeks that never had any. Whenever I go to the IPN history page, I just get a this feature is not available message. I know it's now working because I can see three transactions in our database (that come through the IPN listener)

On another note, if I go to the download history page and try to click download, the page refreshes but nothing happens. I don't get a report or anything, any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though you're looking for the IPN history page, where you can resend IPNs: https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_display-ipns-history

Late edit: changed title to better reflect the true question (it's not about *regenerating* IPNs).  And the answer is it's not possible. Instead, for past IPN-less activity one must manually import a CSV obtained from www.paypal.com account home -> Reports -> Activity Download

This is the URL: https://business.paypal.com/merchantdata/reportHome

If once in the Activity Download, "Create Report" does not work properly (e.g. "nothing happens"), contact PayPal's support for assistance as that is not normal.

Comment: No the problem was IPN was not set up initially so payments went through with it off and there is no IPN history. I was wondering if you can ask paypal somehow to go generate IPN data for records that previously didn't have it, but the answer is no. But thanks for the answer anyways!

Comment: Oh -- no for that you need to import a CSV obtained from the Reports -> Activity Download.  This is the URL: https://business.paypal.com/merchantdata/reportHome.  If Activity Download -> "Create Report" does not work, contact PayPal's support